# Proving: $a^2 < b^2 ⇔ |a| < |b|$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, real-numbers

I started studying mechanical engineering and it works perfectly fine for me but i stumbled across this problem:

$$a^2 < b^2 ⇔ |a| < |b|$$

I found a solution but that took me a full piece of paper and I am sure it can be solved quicker.
I would be very happy if someone could help me proving the (obvious equation).

Greetings, 
Finn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ increases and from here we obtain: $$a^2<b^2\Leftrightarrow\sqrt{a^2}<\sqrt{b^2}\Leftrightarrow|a|<|b|.$$

Your second inequality:
We need to prove that
$$|a+b|+|a-b|\geq|a|+|b|$$ or
$$(a+b)^2+2|a^2-b^2|+(a-b)^2\geq a^2+2|ab|+b^2$$ or
$$a^2-2|ab|+b^2+2|a^2-b^2|\geq0$$ or
$$(|a|-|b|)^2+2|a^2-b^2|\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Comment: That's it? I feel really stupid right now

Comment: @Finn Eggers It's all. I used also that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: I am currently stuck with an other inequality. It would be great if you could also help me with this one: 

|a + b| + |a−b| ≥ |a| + |b|