# Proving that: $ | a + b | + |a-b| \ge|a| + |b|$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, absolute-value

I am trying to prove this for nearly an hour now:

> $$
> \tag{$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$}| a + b |  + |a-b| \ge|a| + |b|
> $$

I'm lost, could you guys give me a tip from where to start, or maybe show a good resource for beginners in proofs ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: a and b are elements of the real numbers

Comment: B.t.w., this is an inequality, not an inequation, and it has to be proved, not to be solved.

Comment: Sorry for that :)

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476928/proving-simple-equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestions would be the following.

1. First observe that it is symmetric in $a$ and $b$. Moreover, it's certainly true when $a = b$.
2. Note also that if we replace $b$ with $-b$, then the claim is unchanged. So we may assume $b \ge 0$. The same holds for $a$.
3. It also shows us that, without loss of generality, we can assume that $a > b$. If $a > b$, then this tells us something useful: $|a - b| = a - b$.

So we need only consider $a > b \ge 0$. I leave the rest of the argument to you (although there's not much left). Hopefully this helps show how one might approach these questions, not just give you an almost-solution to one particular question :)

Comment: can you explain why we can assume that |a−b|=a−b ?

Comment: Note that the inequality is symmetric in $a$ and $b$: swapping them has no effect. We must have $a \ge b$ or $b \ge a$. Since we can swap $a$ and $b$, without loss of generality we just assume that it's $a$ that is larger. Does that explain it? :)

Comment: Oh yeah..... Now i see it... :)

Answer (score 13):

Using triangle inequality,
$$|a+b| + |a-b| \geqslant |(a+b) + (a - b)| = 2|a|$$
also as $|a-b| = |b-a|$,
$$|a+b| + |a-b| \geqslant |(a+b) + (b - a)| = 2|b|$$
Now add and conclude!

Comment: So it works in $\mathbb{C}$ and even in any normed vector space.

Answer (score 2):

Start with $|a|+|b|$ and rewrite $a$ and $b$ as $\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{a-b}{2}$ and $\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}$ respectively. Use the triangle inequality.

Comment: In other words, if $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $y=\frac{a-b}{2}$ this is equivalent to $|x+y|+|x-y|\leq 2|x|+2|y|$.

Answer (score 2):

To prove
$$
| a + b |  + |a-b| \ge|a| + |b|
$$

Square both the sides. This does not change inequality. We have

$$
| a + b |^2  + |a-b|^2 + 2|a+b||a-b| \ge|a|^2 + |b|^2 + 2|a||b|
$$

$$
(|a|^2 + |b|^2 +2|a||b|cos\theta) + (|a|^2 + |b|^2 -2|a||b|cos\theta) + 2|a+b||a-b| \ge|a|^2 + |b|^2 + 2|a||b|
$$ where $\theta$ is angle between a and b

$$
2|a|^2 + 2|b|^2  + 2|a+b||a-b| \ge|a|^2 + |b|^2 + 2|a||b|
$$

$$
|a|^2 + |b|^2  + 2|a+b||a-b| \ge 2|a||b|
$$

$$
|a|^2 + |b|^2  + 2|a+b||a-b| - 2|a||b| \ge 0 
$$

$$
(|a|-|b|)^2  + 2|a+b||a-b|\ge 0 
$$

So on left hand side we have both terms which are always greater than 0, hence this inequality always holds

Equality exists when a=b

QED

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $|a|\geq |b|$. Since the terms are all non-negative, by squaring both sides, we obtain the equivalent inequality
$$(a + b)^2  + (a-b)^2 +2(a^2-b^2)\ge a^2+b^2+2|a||b|$$
that is
$$3a^2-b^2\ge 2|a||b|\Leftrightarrow (3|a|+|b|)(|a|-|b|)\geq 0$$
which holds. Therefore the given inequality is always true.

Comment: How do you know that a >= b?

Comment: We solve the inequality for $a\geq b$. For $b\geq a$, we simply swap $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I see this geometrically in $\mathbb{C}$: let's say we have two complex numbers $a, b$ and consider the parallelogram formed by $0, a, a + b, b$. The midpoints of the diagonals coincide at the point $\frac{a + b}{2}$. These diagonals cut the parallelogram into four triangles, on each of which we can perform the triangle inequality. We get the following inequalities:

\begin{align*}
|a - 0| &\le \left| a - \frac{a + b}{2} \right| + \left| \frac{a + b}{2} - 0 \right| \\
|(a + b) - a| &\le \left| (a + b) - \frac{a + b}{2} \right| + \left| \frac{a + b}{2} - a \right| \\
|b - (a + b)| &\le \left| b - \frac{a + b}{2} \right| + \left| \frac{a + b}{2} - (a + b) \right| \\
|0 - b| &\le \left| a - \frac{a + b}{2} \right| + \left| \frac{a + b}{2} - 0 \right|
\end{align*}
Simplifying the above inequalities and summing them up yields the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

\begin{eqnarray}
|a+b|+|a-b| &=& \max(a+b,-a-b)+\max(a-b,b-a) \\
&=& \max(2a, 2b, -2b, -2a) \\
&=& 2 \max(|a|,|b|) \\
&\ge& |a|+|b|
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

From triangular inequality we have

$$\left|u+v\right|+\left|u-v \right|\le |u|+|v|+|u|+|v|=2|u|+2|v|\\ \left|\frac{u+v}{2}\right|+\left|\frac{u-v}{2}\right|\le |u|+|v|\quad(*)$$

set $a+b=u;\;a-b=v$

$$a=\frac{u+v}{2};\;b=\frac{u-v}{2}$$

$| a + b |  + |a-b| \ge|a| + |b|$

$$\left|\frac{u+v}{2}+\frac{u-v}{2}\right|+\left|\frac{u+v}{2}-\frac{u-v}{2}\right|\ge \left|\frac{u+v}{2}\right|+\left|\frac{u-v}{2}\right|$$

$$|u|+|v|\ge \left|\frac{u+v}{2}\right|+\left|\frac{u-v}{2}\right|$$ 
which is true because of $(*)$

Answer (score 0):

**Very Simple Trick: We have that** 
\begin{split} (|a|-|b|)^2 +2|a^2-b^2| \ge 0&\Longleftrightarrow & a^2+b^2 -2|a||b|+ 2|a +b||a-b| \ge 0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow & a^2+b^2 + 2|a +b||a-b|\ge 2|a||b|\\
&\Longleftrightarrow&  \color{red}{2a^2+2b^2} + 2|a +b||a-b|\ge  \color{red}{a^2+b^2}+2|a||b|\\
&\Longleftrightarrow&  (|a +b|+|a-b|)^2 \ge  (|a|+|b|)^2\\
&\Longleftrightarrow&  |a +b|+|a-b| \ge  |a|+|b|\end{split}

Given that $$\color{red}{ (|a +b|+|a-b|)^2 = 2a^2+2b^2 + 2|a +b||a-b|}$$